# How to correctly show author name with translation in bibliography?

Tags: xetex, biber

I want my bibliography entry to begin with Guowuyuan [State Council]. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{document}
\begin{document}

Example\autocite{Guowuyuan}

\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

And the bibliography:

```
@article{Guowuyuan2008, 
entrysubtype ={newspaper},
author = {Guowuyuan[State Council]},
title={Guowuyuan guanyu yinfa Wenchuan dizhen
zaihou huifu chongjian zongtiguihua de tongzhi
[Notice of the State Council on Printing and Distributing
the Master Plan for Rebuilding and Relief after the Wenchuan Earthquake]},
url= {http://www.gov.cn/zhengce/content/2008-09/24/content_6121.htm},
year={2008}, month={9}, day = {19}
}
```

But I get:
[image]

I understand the problem, but have no solution.

Edit:
The ideal placement of the quotation marks was given to me as follows:
[image]

Comment: You can also have a look at the experimental release of biblatex and biber 4.0:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/experimental/

https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/experimental/

This is expressly meant to deal with multilingual bibliographies and citations like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` has a field called `nameaddon` that can be used for things like this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\renewcommand*{\ctitleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Guowuyuan2008, 
  entrysubtype = {newspaper},
  author       = {Guowuyuan},
  nameaddon    = {State Council},
  title        = {Guowuyuan guanyu yinfa Wenchuan dizhen
                  zaihou huifu chongjian zongtiguihua de tongzhi},
  titleaddon   = {Notice of the State Council on Printing and Distributing
                  the Master Plan for Rebuilding and Relief after the Wenchuan Earthquake},
  url          = {http://www.gov.cn/zhengce/content/2008-09/24/content_6121.htm},
  date         = {2008-09-19},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Example\autocite{Guowuyuan2008}

\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Guowuyuan [State Council]. “Guowuyuan guanyu yinfa Wenchuan dizhen zaihou huifu chongjian zongtiguihua de tongzhi.” [Notice of the State Council on Printing and Distributing the Master Plan for Rebuilding and Relief after the Wenchuan Earthquake], September 19, 2008. http://www.gov.cn/zhengce/content/2008-09/24/content 6121.htm.]

Comment: +1. :-) Just out of idle curiosity: Since the contents of the `title` field are typeset in quotation marks, might it be advisable to change `\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}` to `\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{``#1''}}`?

Comment: What do addbibressource and renewcommand do?

Comment: @Ludi `\addbibresource{<filename>.bib}` is `biblatex`'s preferred version of `\bibliography{<filename>}` (which is deprecated in `biblatex`). `\renewcommand{<command name>}{<new definition>}` changes the definition of the command `<command name>` to `<new definition>`.

Comment: Does this work with XeTeX? I get:! LaTeX Error: Command \ctitleaddonpunct undefined.

Comment: @Ludi It does for me. In fact whether you use pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX should make not difference for that. But it is possible that your version of `biblatex-chicago` is older than mine and that the command does not exist in your version (or has a different name). The `\ctitleaddonpunct` is not central to this answer, though, which is `nameaddon`. You can delete that line if it gives you trouble. I just included it to show that you can use `titleaddon` for the translation of the title.

Comment: @moewe I managed to run it on overleaf, replacing autocite{Guowuyuan} with autocite{Guowuyuan2008}. If you happen to also know how to place the quotations as described in the edit, it would be great. But your help is already greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Ludi The quotation mark thingy would be a new question.